# Как это сделать в apache?

Tags: nginx, apache

Nginx:

```
    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        root /var/www/Company/InternalServices;
    }
```

Если файл не найден, возвращаем `index.html`.

Куда прописывать это в apache, в sites available?

Comment: Ищите в .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond REQUEST_URI !-f
RewriteCond REQUEST_URI !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.html [L]
```

Документацию можно почитать тут https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html